# DB2 LoginUser creation through query

Tags: db2

Can anybody tell me the query to create LOGIN USER in DB2_9.5, I want to create it it by firing query from command editor?

Answer (score 1):

DB2 uses the operating system users (or LDAP, etc) for login.  Here is a quote from [Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0006306.html):

> Authentication of a user is completed using a security facility
>   outside of the DB2® database system. The security facility can be part
>   of the operating system or a separate product.

In DB2, the database does not handle user accounts (I.E., there's no equivalent to SQL Server's ["SQL Server Authentication Mode"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx)).